# Android TCP - Socket doesn't get disconnected when app is closed

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to use TCP with an Android app, so there are two projects, one is the server and one is the client.
When I run the server and open the client, everything works fine and messages are being delivered to both sides, although when I close the app (from an emulator), it won't alert me in the console that the socket connection was closed and attempt to get another connection so when trying to re-open the app, it won't reconnect and messages won't be delivered.

So what am I really doing wrong here? I'm new to Android and TCP, so I'm sorry if this is quite a rookie question.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();

    running = true;

    try {
        System.out.println("S: Connecting...");

        //create a server socket. A server socket waits for requests to come in over the network.
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

        //create client socket... the method accept() listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it.
        while (running) {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            try {

                //sends the message to the client
                mOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);

                //read the message received from client
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                //in this while we wait to receive messages from client (it's an infinite loop)
                //this while it's like a listener for messages
                while(!client.isClosed()) {
                    String message = in.readLine();
                    if (message != null && messageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from ServerBoard class
                        messageListener.messageReceived(message);
                    }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("S: Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.close();
                System.out.println("S: Done.");
            }
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("S: Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be more accurate to say that you aren't testing for disconnection correctly.

1. `Socket.isClosed()` does not magically become true when the peer disconnects. So using it to control a read loop is futile. It only tells you whether *you* have closed *this socket.*
2. `readLine()` returns null when the peer has disconnected, but you're treating it as just another value.

A correct loop using `readLine()` looks like this:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Though, I have another question. Does my code support multiple connections simultaneously?

Comment: No. You would need to start a new thread to handle the I/O in each accepted socket. Examples abound. See for example the Custom Networking section of the Oracle Java Tutorial.

Comment: Or move to a different strategy using select. Then you can keep using a single thread.